# Is language "necessarily underspecified"?

Tags: semantics, reference-request, pragmatics, formal-semantics, history-of-linguistics

I've read an exam question given in a class on Semantics, that was asking

> Why is language necessarily underspecified

I did not find much about this at the time, which is surprising because it intuitively strikes me as an important concept.

The class was using J. I. Saeed, "Semantics", which albeit does not index the term. The notion must have been given separately in class. The student couldn't guide me any further either. What I found is too formal, e.g. there's the Wikipedia article [Underspecification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underspecification) focused mainly on phonetic and morphologic underspecification. A random .pdf jumped right inwith syntax trees. Now I found [*Ambiguity* in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ambiguity/), which in turn may be too broad (I should read it eventually).

At any rate, I hope the instructor was not asking the students to synthesize an answer. Rather, I suppose they referred the idea about "necessity" to a certain line of thought, a scholar, or seminal work, in the sense that e.g. "one cannot not communicate" is attributed to Paul Watzlawick, or "I know that I know nothing" to Plato's Sokrates, even if this isn't always completely accurate.

So, looking for an authoritative answer, this is basically a reference request. A discussion, or rather a summary of the  context is welcome, but I'm affraid it would have to be necessarily underspecified and thus may be kept brief.

PS: A search for "semantics underspecified" yields many results. The reference request still stands, as long as I can't answer it myself, while I postpone flipping through the results (18 months later I am none the wiser; who developed the idea?)

Comment: The motto (among some linguists) is "Semantics underspecifies". What they mean by it is that the details, and often the main point, of any combinational utterance is determined by pragmatics, not semantics. In other words, context overrides semantics; most folks who say this view semantics as a semi-formal variety of logic.

Comment: Saeed (4th ed.), Semantics, Glossary, p. 456, there's an explanation of underspecification.

Comment: @jlawler that was my instinctual thought as well.

Comment: Also, you may want to try googling "semantic underspecification" (About 331,000 results)

Comment: @AlexB.: Here we are 2-3 years further down the track, and I only got 7510 results when I cut & pasted your **"semantic underspecification"** into a google search box. Is this evidence that people have recently become far less interested in the phenomenon?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no idea why Google is showing these numbers now. FYI, I just got "About 8,480 results (0.43 seconds)"

Comment: Google gives estimates to speed up the search, it does not retrieve all results when loading the first page. Estimates might improve over time, evidently. I received Saeed eventually with the relevant page, but I don't remember it being particularly informative, by the way.